# How to add pass parameter in column name and get return column in sql function

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

Here is my code :

```
Create or replace test ( a number) :
 Return table ( col+'_'+a) 

$$
Select col as col + '_'+ a from xyz where col=a $$

Select * from test (6)
```

Output:

```
Col_6
123
```

Can you please help here with way to achieve the dynamic column name.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Using snowflakes client